# "R"ify code to save memory and CPU power and / or how to show progress on code execution?

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, dplyr

I wrote a very un-R-like code to do some relatively straightforward calculations but while the code seems to work, it is highly inefficient and my computer's RAM just can't pull it off.

I have a `data.frame` called `dat` with four columns consisting of `firm_id` (`character`), `pnum` (`numeric`), `class` (`character`), and `date` (`Date`). I have a total of 100,000 rows: 200 different `firm_id`, 90,000 unique `pnum`, about 31,000 unique `class` and about as many `date`.

Every `pnum` is unique to a single `firm_id`. `pnum` is assigned to multiple `class` elements (so the `pnum` is repeated in the data.frame 5 times if there are 5 `class` elements. The `date` does not vary per `pnum` but multiple `pnum` of the same `firm_id` can be on the same date. There are `zero NAs`.

Here is a short `dput`

```
dput(dat[1:50])
structure(list(firm_id = c("A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O","A&O", "A&O",
                           "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", 
                           "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", 
                           "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O",
                           "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "A&O", "AAT", 
                           "AAT", "AAT", "AAT", "AAT", "AAT", "AAT", "AAT", 
                           "AAT", "AAT", "AAT", "AAT", "AAT", "AAT", "AAT", "AAT"), 
               pnum = c(5259588, 5259588, 5259588, 5259588, 7049668, 7049668,
                        7049668, 7049668, 7049668, 7049668, 7049668, 7183616, 
                        7183616, 7183616, 7183616, 7183616, 7183616, 7183616,
                        7183616, 7208818, 7208818, 7208818, 7208818, 7208818,
                        7208818, 7208818, 7122882, 7122882, 7122882, 7122882, 
                        7122882, 7122882, 7122882, 7122882, 6413822, 6413822, 
                        6413822, 6413822, 6413822, 6413822, 6413822, 6413822, 6413822,
                        6750507, 6750507, 6750507, 6750507, 6750507, 6750507, 6750507),
               class = c("184/1.5", "222/110", "251/100", "251/324", "257/330",
                         "257/331", "257/401", "257/E29.027", "257/E29.134",
                         "257/E29.136", "257/E29.146", "257/341", "257/342", 
                         "257/343", "257/401", "257/723", "257/E23.052", 
                         "257/E23.079", "257/E25.016", "257/666", "257/676", 
                         "257/E23.024", "257/E23.026", "257/E23.037", "257/E23.044",
                         "257/E23.052", "257/48", "257/666", "257/723", "257/778", 
                         "257/E23.052", "257/E25.013", "257/E25.029", "257/E29.267",
                         "257/331", "257/E29.027", "257/E29.066", "257/E29.133",
                         "257/E29.146", "438/268", "438/270", "438/272", "438/430",
                         "257/302", "257/328", "257/330", "257/396",
                         "257/E29.027", "257/E29.066", "257/E29.133"), 
               date = structure(c(7953, 7953, 7953, 7953, 10463, 10463, 
                                  10463, 10463, 10463, 10463, 10463, 11777,
                                  11777, 11777, 11777, 11777, 11777, 11777,
                                  11777, 12619, 12619, 12619, 12619, 12619, 
                                  12619, 12619, 12724, 12724, 12724, 12724,
                                  12724, 12724, 12724, 12724, 10703, 10703,
                                  10703, 10703, 10703, 10703, 10703, 10703, 
                                  10703, 10703, 10703, 10703, 10703, 10703,
                                  10703, 10703), class = "Date")), 
          .Names = c("firm_id", "pnum", "class", "date"),
          class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
          row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

The code aims to do the following:

For every single `firm_id`:

1. Look at the `class` elements of each `pnum`.
2. Compare those `class` elements to the `class` elements of EACH `pnum` INDIVIDUALLY of the same `firm_id`, provided that the gap between the `dates` (which are tied to the respective `pnum`) that are being compared is smaller than 5 years.  [Added this in capital letters to avoid confusion. Solution provided by Michael below compares the focal `pnum` to the firm's portfolio of `pnum` in the five years before]

My current code looks like this: (I know, trust me I know)

```
#Step 1: Create a vector of unique firms and a data.frame with all
#  `pnum`, `firm_id`, and `date` but without the `class` data

firms <- (unique(dat$firm_id))
patents <- data.frame(unique(dat$pnum))
patents$id <- dat$firm_id[match(patents$unique.dat.pnum, dat$pnum)]
patents$date <- dat$date[match(patents$unique.dat.pnum, dat$pnum)]
colnames(patents) <- c("pnum", "id", "date")

#Step 2: Set-up variables needed to store the results 

library(gtools)
startrow <- 0
df <- data.frame()

#Step 3: Loop around all firms

for(i in 1:length(firms)){
  startrow <- startrow + length(patents$id[patents$id == firms[i - 1]])
  subdat <- dat[dat$firm_id == firms[i]]
  subpat <- unique(subdat$pnum)
  dt <- data.frame()

#Step 4: Find which of the `pnum` fit within the 5 year time frame
    for(j in 1:length(subpat)){    # Number of unique patents in subdat

      class.now <- subdat$class[subdat$pnum == subpat[j]]
      ref.pat <- unique(subdat$pnum[(subdat$date > (patents$date[startrow + j] - 5*365) & subdat$date < (patents$date[startrow + j]))])
      if (invalid(ref.pat) == T ) ref.pat <- NA
          m <- data.frame(cbind(orig.pat = rep(patents$pnum[startrow + j],length(ref.pat))),ref.pat = NA, jac = NA)

#Step 5: Compare the focal `pnum` with each of the prior ones within the
#  5 year time frame and calculate a Jaccard index

              for(k in 1:length(ref.pat)){
                class.ref <- subdat$class[subdat$pnum == ref.pat[k]]
                m$ref.pat[k] <- ref.pat[k]
                m$jac[k] <- sum(class.now %in% class.ref)/(length(class.now) + length(class.ref) - length(class.now %in% class.ref))}
            dt <- data.frame(rbind(dt, m)) ; rm(m)           
        } 
    df <- data.frame(rbind(df, dt))
    rm(dt) ; print(i)
  }
```

EDIT 1: The code results in a data.frame `df` with the first column `origpat` containing the original `pnum`, the second column `ref.pat` containing the patents with which `orig.pat` is compared, and the third column `jac` the Jaccard index of both `orig.pat` and `ref.pat`.

Any suggestions on making this work better are very welcome!

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question as such, but I'm voting to transfer it over to Code Review, where it might get a better reception.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I honestly was not aware there was a separate forum for code reviews...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this gets the right thing, I admit I got a wee lost in your original code & description.

```
# helper function for conciseness below
jac <- function(cn, cr) sum(idx <- cn %in% cr) /
  (length(cn) + length(cr) - length(idx))

setkey(dat, pnum, firm_id) #for faster exclusive subsetting

dat[ , {x<-date[1]; cs <- class #assign these so there's no scoping issue below
#Now that we're within a (firm_id, pnum) subset,
#  we go back to the original table and subset to
#  the _same_ firm but NOT the same patent
#  (note that the current firm and pnum are stored
#   in .BY[[1]] and .BY[[2]], respectively)
dat[firm_id == .BY[[1]] & pnum != .BY[[2]]
      #having subsetted to everything by the same firm
      #  (except things with the same `pnum`), we
      #  check which `pnum` satisfy the within-five-years
      #  criterium; for those that do, we calculate `jac`
      ][abs(date - x) <= 365 * 5,  jac(cs, class)]}, 
by = .(firm_id, pnum)] #we do this for each `firm_id` and `pnum`
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, will try to run it shortly but I'm trying to understand one thing first (thanks for the edits!):  Where is the result stored? The result of my code (which I forgot to describe) creates a new data.frame `df` in which the focal patent and the patent with which it is compared are stored in a matrix next to their respective Jaccard index. My code is currently running but it only finished 8 `firm_id` in just over an hour.

Comment: @SJDS You can simply assign the result of this operation -- prepend `result <- dat[...]`

Comment: @SJDS you said `df` has the "focal" patent _and_ the comparison patent? I think I misunderstood, then (my own naivete about what a Jaccard index is). The code as stands compares each firm's patent to _all_ other patents within five years _as a whole_ (instead of one-by-one). I don't think the difference is too difficult to en-code; you are aiming for one-by-one?

Comment: Yeah, your code just finished running and I noticed that it indeed produces a comparison between the focal patent and the portfolio of the last five years. I wrote another code (with for loops) that calculates it for the portfolio as you did and stores the number of overlapping classes, the number of class in the focal patent, and the number of classes in the portfolio. To my surprise, my double for-loop takes significantly less time to run to establish the comparison with the portfolio. Running your code through my dataset took about 90 minutes...

Comment: The `pnum` by `pnum` comparison is in my eyes more difficult because of the computational limitations. The highest number of rows in `dat` for one `firm_id` is just over 80,000 (total number of classes) for about 15,000 unique `pnum`. As a consequence the `pnum` by `pnum` dataframe grows exponentially. A good solution would be to automatically reshape all the ones for which the Jaccard is zero into one line with just the focal `pnum` and a count for the number of other `pnum` with zero Jaccard